# How to give name on different instances of the same class on iOS - iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, loops, instance, names

I am developing an iPhone application which has a lot of different cards, each one of those represents a car. So, every card has some instance variables and one image. My class CarCard is loading data for each car from a .plist file. I want to make many instances in a loop so as to give different name to each instance. E.g:

```
CarCard *car1 = [[CarCard alloc] initWithSomeINfo: info];
....... *car2 ..........................................;

....... *carN ..........................................;
```

where N is the number of Cars. The problem is that I do not know what the number N is each time. So i have to make the instances in a loop, but i could not find how to give different names to instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `NSMutableArray` of `CarCard` objects is a much better way to go. Instantiate it outside of your loop:

```
NSMutableArray *cardArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

then inside your loop you'll add your objects:

```
[cardArray addObject:car];
```

Now you can access them by their indices:

```
// Card 9, numbering starts at 0
myCar = [cardArray objectAtIndex:8];
```

---

**Edited to add**

If you want to refer to the cards by their name instead of their position in the array and the names will be unique, you can use a dictionary and refer to the cards by name. Instantiate the dictionary outside of the loop:

```
NSMutableDictionary *cardDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

then inside the loop you'll add your objects:

```
[cardDictionary setObject:car forKey:cardName];
```

Now you can access them by their names:

```
// Card with the key named "card9"
myCar = [cardDictionary objectForKey:@"card9"];

// Card with the key named "monkey"
myCar = [cardDictionary objectForKey:@"monkey"];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The problem is that i will use these cards for a multiplayer game. So i want to send to the otherPlayer the names of the cards that HE is going to have on his deck and the names of the OPPONENTS cards, so as to give the information he needs to make 2 decks (after shuffle). Then, both players should compare the attributes of their cards and so , it would be useful if each instance had a unique name, so as to send via the internet only the card instance name and not the hole card instance. Any ideas about that?

Comment: The idea of a central deck still holds though, right, a deck from which the players get their own cards? So you build the deck as an array, then deal/split the cards, creating Hands of cards that are identified by their position in the deck and the card name that you also stored in the master deck. You send the players the card names and indices in the master array, and when they play a card they only have to send you the the index. I'll add one other thing to my answer that might work better for you, using an `NSMutableDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create instances of CarCard and simply add them to an array? If you know what N is, then your loop is pretty simple:

```
NSMutableArray *carCards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:N];
for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    NSDictionary *car = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:<plist-i>];
    CarCard *carCard = [[[CarCard alloc] initWithSomeInfo:car] autorelease];
    [carCards addObject:carCard];
}
```

Something like this. Is this helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an NSMutableDictionary and populate it. Assuming you already know (from the plist) how many values you need to create, you could write something like this:

```
for (int count = 1; count <= totalCars; count++)
     [carDict setObject:[[CarCard alloc] initWithSomeInfo:info] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"car%d", count]];
```

Then you could get any numbered object:

```
CarCard someCard = [carDict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"car%d", selectedNumber]];
```

Alternatively, you can use NSDictionary's `allValues` method to get an array of the values:

```
NSArray *allCards = [carDict allValues];
```